# prepare resource id from selected spinner item string

Tags: android, resources, spinner

i have a spinner with various items that i use to get text from selected item.

i want to use this text to prepare a resource id for openRawResource, my code looks like

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.accident);
    String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String newt = "R.raw." + text;
    int textxx = Integer.parseInt(newt); 

    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(textxx);
```

but it does not work, any ideas

Comment: why you are using string here.. if you can get resource id as integer directly

Comment: i want the resource opened(text file) to be based on user selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
int textxx = Integer.parseInt(newt);
```

The correct way to do it is :

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(text, "raw", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
```

Now you can use the `InputStream` as follows :

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(resID);
```

### EDIT

> does not allow getPackageName() says its indefined

If you are on an `Activity` you can do it :

```
this.getPackageName(); //this -> context
```

If you are on a `Fragment` you can do it :

```
getActivity().getPackageName();
```

> but only opens the first item in the spinner does not open other files when i select other items

You need to implement [`onItemSelected()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) see the code below.

```
final Spinner sp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            // your code here
            String text = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(text, "raw", getPackageName());
            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(resID);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });
```

Comment: does not allow getPackageName() says its indefined

Comment: Try using `getApplicationContext().getPackageName();`

Comment: this has worked but only opens the first item in the spinner does not open other files when i select other items

Comment: That's because you need to implement the `setOnItemSelectedListener()` see my edit...

Answer (score 0):

Try this
add this to strings.xml:

```
  <string-array name="raw_resources">
        <item>@raw/yourresource1</item>
        <item>@raw/yourresource2</item>
        <item>@raw/yourresource3</item>
        <item>@raw/yourresource4</item>
        <item>@raw/yourresource5</item>
    </string-array>
```

Now in your fragment access it like this:

```
final TypedArray resourceIDS = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.select_sounds);
        int[] resIds = new int[sounds.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < sounds.length(); i++) {
            resIds[i] = sounds.getResourceId(i, -1);
        }
resourceIDS.recycle();
```

Now you have all the ids of the raw file ids in resIds array. Just index it based on what item is selected in the spinner.

Comment: does not allow getPackageName() says its indefined

Comment: This is because you are calling getPackageName() in a fragment so try getActivity().getPackageName()

Comment: this has worked but only opens the first item in the spinner does not open other files when i select other items

Answer (score 0):

A first idea would be to use a HashMap to look up the ResID of the desired value. However, this has an issue where the 'String' needs to be unique or you could get some very bad behavior (entries overwriting each other when you fill up the hashmap)

But [Resources has a method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) that does this lookup for you

```
/*
Return a resource identifier for the given resource name. 
A fully qualified resource name is of the form "package:type/entry". The
first two components (package and type) are optional if defType and
defPackage, respectively, are specified here.

Note: use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to
retrieve resources by identifier than by name.
*/
public int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)
```

So try this:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.accident);
String resName = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

int resID= this.getResources().getIdentifier(
             resName, "raw", this.getPackageName());

InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(resID);
```

Comment: added (untested) example code for you. ("raw" might need to "id", not 100% sure without trying it out)